# Property is always undefined in React component

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have a simple React component that should retrieve some objects from an api and display them on screen. The problem is, the property holding my data always seems to have an undefined value. In C#, I have a Property class:

```
public class Property
{
    public int PropertyID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

My component's parent gets a list of these from an api and passes them in as props. 
Here's my component:

```
export interface IPropertySearchResult {
    PropertyID: number,
    Name: string
}

export interface IPropertySearchResults {
    Results: IPropertySearchResult[]
}

export interface IPropertyWindowProps {
    Properties: IPropertySearchResults
}

export interface IPropertyWindowState {
}

export class PropertyWindow extends React.Component<IPropertyWindowProps, 
IPropertyWindowState> {
    constructor(props: IPropertyWindowProps) {
    super(props);
    }

render() {
    return (
        <div >
            <ul>
                {
                    this.props.Properties && this.props.Properties.Results ?                        
                        this.props.Properties.Results.map((p: IPropertySearchResult, idx: number) =>
                            <li key={idx}> <PropertyEditor Property={p} /> </li>)                        
                        : 'properties null'
                }
            </ul>
        </div>
    );
}
```

}

As shown in the image below, this.props.Properties contains the objects I need but for some reason this.props.Properties.Results is always marked as undefined.

[image: screenshot].

**Update**

I think the problem has something to do with the way I'm reading the data. I have my controller:

```
[HttpGet("Search")]
public IActionResult GetProperties()
{
    var props = new Property[]
    {
        new Property(){PropertyID=1, Name="default1"},
        new Property(){PropertyID=2, Name="default2"},
        new Property(){PropertyID=3, Name="default3"},
        };

        return Ok(new { Properties = props });
    }
}
```

And its client:

```
export class PropertyReader {
    public static search(): Promise<IPropertySearchResults> {
        return new Promise<IPropertySearchResults>((resolve, reject) => {
            axios.get(`api/Settings/Search`)
                .then(res => {
                    resolve(res.data);
                });
        });
    }
}
```

Then my component's parent calls the client:

```
    componentDidMount() {
        PropertyReader.search()
            .then(p => this.setState({ properties: p }));
    }
```

For some reason, it's creating an IPropertySearchResults and putting the data into a dynamically added array rather than into the Results array.

Comment: I see `this.props.Properties.properties` array, not `this.props.Properties.Results`

Comment: because those objects do not have a property Results defined. For some reason there is one level of indirection missing.

Comment: What if you drop the IPropertySearchResults interface and make Properties -Property of IPropertyWindowProps directly an IPropertySearchResult[] ?

Comment: I'm afraid I've tried that but to no avail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out, this had a really silly solution. The values were getting save to a property with a lower case name. I had to change

```
export interface IPropertySearchResults {
    Results: IPropertySearchResult[]
}
```

to

```
export interface IPropertySearchResults {
    results: IPropertySearchResult[]
}
```